# How do the witches work in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Does it summon skeletons from dead troops or does it summon them from nowhere? When does a witch attack and when does it summon?

Comment: The flavor text for the witch (when you check the info for her in your dark barracks) states "constantly raising dead warriors from past battles to lead her attacks." This seems to imply that there are enough skeletons from "past battles" so that she can just create them whenever and wherever she happens to be.

Answer (score 2):

The witch summons them out of thin air. She will summon skeletons about every 10-13 seconds, summoning 2 of them each time until the max number of active skeletons is reached.

Comment: 50 percent of your answer is completely fake and false

Comment: Quite frankly, if someone says my answer is wrong but doesn't provide the correct one, I automatically assume it's a troll

Comment: For lvl 1, six skeletons is the limit. So if all 6 are alive, then she cannot summon anymore, correct ? If skeletons die she can keep summoning them endlessly isnt it ?

Comment: @Raestloz I did provide the correct answer. My source is the Clash of Clans Wiki

Comment: I never said you didn't, I simply state what I would do in the hypothetical scenario. I also ignore trolls. @GoodSp33d: correct

Comment: Oh in that case then never mind... But I'm not a troll!

Answer (score 2):

No, she does not summon Skeletons out of thin air. When she summons them, it appears that they come out of the ground in a certain radius of the Witch. The Witch summons every 6 seconds and so on until she summons the max amount of Skeletons, which is 6 for Level 1 Witch and 8 for Level 2 Witch. She attacks every 0.7 seconds with a range of four tiles. My source and more information can be found at the [Clash of Clans Wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Witch). Summoning from the ground (any ground/land) is just a coll feature to make the summoning of Skeletons to be more realistic and might scare people just for fun. There is no special effect from the summoning other than the Skeletons. There doesn't need to be any past corpses. She will continue to spawn Skeletons, if you have any killed troops or not.

Comment: so she does not summon from thin air but ground. does the ground properties have any effect? does there have to be corpses of past barbarians where she is? does she summon from inside building remains? grasslands?

Comment: She summons them from wheverever she is standing, and it makes no difference where that is

Comment: @Esq There is no practical difference to gameplay. This answer has just taken a pedantic stand against the expression *out of thin air*.

Answer (score 1):

From the moment she is deployed, the witch summon 3 skeletons at level 1 each 6 seconds with a max of 6 skeletons. At level 2 she summons 4 skeletons each 6 seconds with a max of 8 skeletons.

Skeletons are summoned anytime anywhere out of the ground.

She attacks by herself when she comes near a building or enemy troops. But she is weak so don't expect too much from her.

Answer (score 0):

A witch summons a number of skeletons ([Larry's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pz6vXH1LCvo)) depending on its [level](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Witch). 
The skeletons are generated out of nothing and come up in close proximity to where the witch is located.

The witch will use her ranged attack as long as she is not in her summoning animation for the skeletons.

I looked for the exact frequency at which witches spawn skeletons but I found numerous answers places.

The witch by herself is has very low HP and low attack damage. Same goes for her skeletons. Witches are often used for distraction troops but some skilled players can use a large amount of witches to do a lot of damage to a base.